# OkHttp вернуть результат запроса в другой класс

Tags: java, android, post, okhttp

Есть отдельный класс для `post` запроса на сервер.

```
public class Post {
private static final MediaType JSON
        = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

  public void post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .build();
     defaultHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
         @Override
         public void onFailure(final Call call, IOException e) {
             // Error
         }

         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws
                 IOException {
             String res = response.body().string();
             Log.d("TAG", "response is: "+res);
             // Do something with the response
         }
     });   
    }
}
```

В другом классе создается объект этого класса и вызывается метод запроса

```
 Post postRequest = new Post();
 postRequest.post(postURL, userLoginData);
```

Как можно вернуть результат из класса `post` в класс, вызывающий метод? Знаю, что нужно как-то инициализировать `Callback` но как это сделать - без понятия

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передайте коллбэк как параметр при вызове метода `post`, и верните результат в него:

```
public class Post {

    // Создаём интерфейс для коллбэка
    public static interface MyCallback {
        void onResult(String result);
    }

    private static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    OkHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

    public void post(String url, String json, MyCallback callback) throws IOException {
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();

        defaultHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                String res = response.body().string();

                // возвращаем результат в коллбэк
                callback.onResult(res);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(final Call call, IOException e) {
                // handle error
            }    
        });

    }

}
```

Затем при вызове:

```
Post post = new Post();

post.post("", "", new Post.MyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(String result) {
        // получили результат из коллбэка и делаем что хотим
        Log.d("TAG", "response is: " + result);
    }
});
```